# Form submit not working while using Ajax of jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

submit button (secondbutton) is not working if it comes from ajax page (Ajax.php) using jquery. In some browser it is working well. But, in some browser not working for example like some mobile browsers. plz help me to do.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>       
            <html lang="ta">
            <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#MyRegister").on('submit', function(){
              if ($("#Button").val()=="FirstButton") {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "Ajax.php",
                      method: "GET"
                   })
                .done(function(response) {
                    $("#Opj").html(response);
               });
                return false;
                 }
                return true;
             });
            </script> 
          </head>
            <body>
            <form id="MyRegister" method="post" action="Target.php">    
            <input id="MyName" type="text">
            <div id="Opj">  <input type="submit" id="Button" value="FirstButton"></div>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Ajax.php

```
<input type="submit" id="Button" value="SecondButton">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to bind the new button to the form like the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834998/bind-dynamically-added-form-to-submit-event-with-jquery/#answer-836193)

Comment: no, that is different question. but here i have only single form. but the secondbutton is not working which is comes from Ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

Your JS has several syntax errors, try fixing them before trying again. If you're concise with the indentation you'll find syntax errors very easily.

Cleaned code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#MyRegister").on('submit', function(){
    if ($("#Button").val()=="FirstButton") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "Ajax.php",
        method: "GET"
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        $("#Opj").html(response);
      });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: i have edited the question now with your help. But still it is  not working in some browsers. can you help me more.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "some browsers"? Also what errors are you getting?

Comment: Secondbotton is getting action is nothing.

Comment: by secondbutton could not submit the form.

Comment: can you help me anything more?

Comment: Add an `.error()` promise to the ajax; use breakpoints and step through the code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code